# WPF: More efficient way of displaying quickly-changing images?

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing, performance

I'm using the **Image** control to display an 8-bit grayscale image that I process myself on a background thread. Once the image is processed, I set the Image.BitmapSource property to point to a new bitmap I create via **BitmapSource.Create().** This is all well and good - until I have to rapidly reprocess the image and throw it back on screen.

The project that I'm working on requires that I be able to reprocess and refresh the image at ~15-20 FPS. I can get images to the UI that fast - that isn't the problem. The problem is the display flickers in an unpleasant way. I'd like to avoid this.

Pre-WPF versions of my project relied on GDI to do this and were able to handle it without the flickering. I'd prefer to not use GDI (or GDI+).

Is there a more efficient WPF-way of doing this?

Comment: I voted to close this as an exact duplicate, Scott pointed out a very similar question. Feel free to vote to close as a duplicate, thanks!

Comment: You can delete your own questions without having them closed you know

Comment: @ChrisF, it's telling me there are too many existing answers to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think question has been asked before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812288/how-to-display-quick-updating-images-without-large-memory-allocation).